# Adding a number to a value every week

Tags: php, addition

I need to add +1 to a value every week at Thursday for example..
Let's assume the value is 5.
Its the 1st of the month and its Thursday.
I want 5 to change to 6 by the 8th of the month.
How do I do that?

I started to come up with something, but since I've never really learned PHP properly I didn't really know what I was doing.

```
$value = 5;
$num = $value + 1;
```

BUT, then the $value stays the same and the $num won't change.

Thanks!

Comment: I hate to ask the obvious, but are you storing in a database? How are you storing this?

Comment: if you have some RDBMS under hand, like mysql/postgresql, you'll better use the standard date functions: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format  It saves a lot of time on managing particular cases like leap-year etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest would be to store an initial date and a starting value. "On July 14th, the value is 5":

```
$initial_date = strtotime('2011-07-14');
$initial_value = 5;

$new_value = $initial_value + floor($initial_date / 86400 / 7);
```

This will dynamically caculate how many weeks have elapsed since the intial date, and add it to the initial value, giving you your new value.

Answer (score 0):

yes, value stays the same.
If you want to change value, just do it like this

```
$value = 5;
$value += 1; //or $value++;
```

Answer (score 0):

Without storing the updated value weekly (in a file or database), you'll have to hardcode the starting timestamp and calculate how many weeks (1 week = 604800 seconds) have passed since then every to determine what to add to `$value = 5`.